# Unsure whether the clause in this sentence is restrictive or nonrestrictive

Tags: commas, which-that, non-restrictive, parenthetical-commas

> I wanted you to have something tangible in these times, in which very little is concrete.

For more context: this is at the end of a letter that has already established that 'these times' = difficult times, uncertain times etc.

Why I think it is nonrestrictive: 'these' already limits 'times'.

Why I think it should perhaps be restrictive: without the clause, the sentence makes less sense... although not no sense. But when we are thinking about 'sense' - is it just grammatical sense or semantic sense?

Would be grateful to hear feedback!

Comment: The comma in writing, and the comma intonation in speech, mark it as a nonrestrictive relative clause modifying _these times_. The distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses is a syntactic one, and depends on intonation and relative pronoun choice (you can't use _that_ with a non-restrictive relative, but you can with a restrictive), not some vague notion of "making sense". That's not grammar.

Comment: The clause makes sense as either restrictive or non-restrictive, so you can either leave the comma out or put it in.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The comma in writing, and the comma intonation in speech, mark it as a nonrestrictive relative clause modifying *these times*. The distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses is a syntactic one, and depends on intonation and relative pronoun choice (you can't use *that* with a non-restrictive relative, but you can with a restrictive), not some vague notion of "making sense". That's not grammar.